# How to display selected option while editing data in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have form with owner names, when I want to edit it, the value goes back like in create function. what I want to ask how to get the value I've selected in edit function?
I have join the owner table with memo data table.

This is my Model:

```
public function get_owner_data(){

    $result = $this->db->get('tbl_owner')
        ->result();
    return $result;
}
```

This is my view

```
<div class="form-group is-empty">
    <select class="form-control" name="client_id">
        <option value="">Select Client</option>
        <?php $client = $this->Admin_model->get_client_data();
            foreach($client as $val){
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $val->client_id; ?>" ><?php echo $val->client_name; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: @yuliantosaparudin can you help me with this

Comment: Could you please tell your problem more specific?

Comment: @ShivaniPatel i am unable to add images so i cant explain in details bt what i can say is i want to display selected value when i edit the form from above code i get all the values which are present in table

Comment: <option  <?= $val->client_id == $selected_id ? 'selected' : ''?> value="<?php echo $val->client_id; ?>" ><?php echo $val->client_name; ?></option> 


Take $selected_id as per you requirement

Comment: @ShivaniPatel can you please share me ur Emailid so i can explain

Comment: shp@narola.email

Comment: @ShivaniPatel did you got my email??

Answer (score 0):

Please refer code below.

```
<option value="<?php echo $val->client_id; ?>" <?php if($val->client_id == $client_id) { ?> selected <?php } ?> ><?php echo $val->client_name; ?></option>
```

Where $client_id is the variable for client in owner's form`

```
<div class="form-group is-empty">
        <select class="form-control" name="client_id">
            <option value="">Select Client</option>
            <?php $client = $this->Admin_model->get_client_data();
            foreach($client as $val){
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $val->client_id; ?>" <?php if($val->client_id == $client_id) { ?> selected <?php } ?> ><?php echo $val->client_name; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: Did not work it gives error as Undefined variable:client_id

Comment: You have to use the variable that stores client_id, in your case, I guess $result->client_id will help you instead of client_id

Comment: No, no, no. Do not access your model from your view.  This is not proper MVC design.   Your controller should be receiving data from the model and passing it to the view.

Answer (score 0):

use this code. i hope this will works for you.

```
   <div class="form-group is-empty">
    <select class="form-control" name="client_id">
        <option value="">Select Client</option>
        <?php $client = $this->Admin_model->get_client_data();
        foreach($client as $val){
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $val->client_id; ?>" <?php echo !empty($client_id) && $client_id == $val->client_id ? "selected" : ''; ?> ><?php echo $val->client_name; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
      </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: Did not work it gives error as Undefined variable:client_id.I have join 2 tables i am fetching client details from client table where as memo table saves the client_id so how can i access that

Comment: can you show me how to get data of current edit record

Comment: No, no, no. Do not access your model from your view.  This is not proper MVC design.   Your controller should be receiving data from the model and passing it to the view.